# Android Soft Keyboard Example

Tags: android, licensing

So i have a Simple Question , it is Legally Allowed to get the Source Code from the Soft Keyboard Demo in Android , Or the Android Soft Keboard Source Code , in the Android itself , then Modify some thing and Integrate this Keyboard in my Project , as iam Not developping a keyboard application , but i need a soft keyboard as Input Method Service , Does Google Allow it ? ,

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response is here :
http://source.android.com/source/licenses.html

Android is under Apache 2.0 license, so the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks you , but if so , Anyone can take an Android Demo Project , modify somes things and release it ?

Comment: As long as you mention where it comes from. http://www.tldrlegal.com/license/apache-license-2.0-(apache-2.0)

Comment: and i have to put this license in the source code ? where ? This is Great to know , even i i know i have to work by Myself and this is what iam doing But , it can Help Me ...

Comment: Not in the source code, but on whatever page you decide to publish the app on (basically, the play store page of your app)

Comment: but this is too Loong ?!

Comment: No, you just drop 1 lines saying that your work is based on Android sources. Unless (or until) your app gets really big, it will be enough.